# Как спарсить выдачу поисковика с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Необходимо спарсить все url'ы на странице выдачи яндекса, как это сделать?
Вроде бы нашел, как спарсить 1, а как их спарсить все и вывести хотябы на экран

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    my_href = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'link link_outer_yes link_theme_outer path__item i-bem'}).get('href')
    return my_href


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=9582&text=скачать&lr=118890&p=1'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Используйте soup.find_all() и в результате получите список из всех совпадений.

Comment: Пробовал, не понятно почему, но сразу появляются ошибки - http://prntscr.com/kgopyv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `soup.find_all`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


def get_data_items(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'organic__url'})

    return [a.get('href') for a in items]


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=9582&text=скачать&lr=118890&p=1'
    print(get_data_items(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Результат:

```
['https://mp3poisk.info/', 'https://ipleer.fm/', 'http://Torrent-Games.net/', 'http://torrentom.com/', 'https://myzcloud.me/', 'http://zaycev.ru.net/', 'http://mzmuz.ru/', 'https://www.besplatnyeprogrammy.ru/', 'http://n-torrents.ru/', 'http://n-torrents.ru/load/pc_games/1', 'http://download-software.ru/']
```

Comment: Спасибо за код, работает как надо.