# Не запускается парсер, т.е никакой ошибки нет и не работает не понимаю в чём проблемы

Tags: python, парсер

Код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests


product = input()

url = "https://www.avito.ru/cheboksary?q=" + product #Либо моя ссылка не правильная 
requests = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.text, "html.parser")


all_links = bs.find_all("a", class_="iva-item-title-py3i_")

for link in all_links:
    print(link)
```

Или я не знаю где ошибку искать.

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests


product = input()

url = "https://www.avito.ru/cheboksary?q=" + product
requests = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.text, "html.parser")


all_links = bs.find_all("a", class_="iva-item-title-py3i_")

for link in all_links:
    print(link)

Comment: Что означает "не работает"? У тебя первая строка запрашивает текст. Ты его вводишь?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, у вас не хватает такой важной части ссылки, как категория. Но, даже если без нее, просто распечатайте текст в терминале и вы увидите вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, у вас просто нет доступа к коду. Ну и если вы сохраните код и откроете сохраненную страницу, будет отображено следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, Авито просто не дает доступа к коду страницы непонятным парсерам. Они уже настолько привыкли, что их парсят, что сделали от этого защиту. Вам нужно попробовать использовать вместо requests библиотеку [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). (https://www.selenium.dev/).

Comment: Блин , я только junior python и слабо понимаю у вас есть свободное время чтобы объяснить это по Discord ?

Comment: У меня нет Discord, к сожалению. Но, можете посмотреть похожий пример вот здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1443521/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd/1443542#1443542